# docker tool box windows 10 が起動できません。

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

ノートパソコン、デスクトップパソコン二台を持ってますがノーパソの場合同じインストール方法でちゃんと起動できています。

もう一台も同じ環境（windows 10 home) なのですが画像のようなメッセージが出てます。

試したこと
翻訳機をかけてホストオンリーがあるかoracle vmで確認したところ何もありませんでした。
手動で指定してくださいのところはやり方がわからなくて詰まってます。

docker, vm の再インストールも４回ほどしたのですが同じでした。

```
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation windows is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
Regenerate TLS machine certs? Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...

This machine has been allocated an IP address, but Docker Machine could not reach it successfully.

SSH for the machine should still work, but connecting to exposed ports, such as the Docker daemon port (usually <ip>:2376), may not work properly.

You may need to add the route manually, or use another related workaround.

This could be due to a VPN, proxy, or host file configuration issue.

You also might want to clear any VirtualBox host only interfaces you are not using.
```

[image]

Comment: この記事が情報量も多くて何か参考になるかも。[Windows10 Home に Docker Toolbox を使って Docker をインストールするまでの戦いの記録](https://neos21.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/11/03/162430)

Comment: 書かれているメッセージからすると、古いですがこの記事が近いのかも。[Windows で docker を動かそうとしたらホストオンリーネットワークが溢れて詰まった](https://qiita.com/chiepomme/items/835894e58e249bf19790)

Comment: @penguin222 さん、エラーメッセージには「VPN やプロキシが原因の場合もあります」と書かれています。これらは利用されていますか。

Comment: nekketsuuu さん返答ありがとうございます。
全く使っておりません・・・

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。　全部試してみます！